# How can i make a sub for a keypress event?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on an excel with macros. I have a userform with textboxes, several of them use a function for only press numbers.

[image: Example of UserForm]

```
Private Sub quantity1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case Asc("0") To Asc("9")
        Case Else
        KeyAscii = 0
    End Select
End Sub
```

How can i put the select case on a procedure or function
and then call it from any keypress event that i need it (in this case, quantity1 quantity2, price1 and price2, but no in buyer)?
I tried making a sub that uses the same parameters like the event e.g:

```
Sub Only_Numbers(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
```

Comment: What you need is a control array to handle `_KeyPress`. Unfortunately my site is under renovation else I would have pointed you to a complete example. You may now have to search the web for VBA Control Arrays

Comment: Could you explain more about what this form needs to do? Does it need to run in the background?

Comment: "Help me" is not a question.  Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: @ashleedawg Its a userform with some textboxes where you can put values that goes to a table later.

Comment: @fjatp - ...then I don't understand why you wouldn't just use the regular textbox entry method?

Comment: @ashleedawg Because I need the user to only place numbers for quantity and prices and are like 10 textboxes that requires that condition.

Comment: I have posted a reply. See if that is what you want?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Wow! Awesome Reply! it's almost like that, but i require that certain textboxes (not all) on the userform could have this restriction.
I guess that if i do this 
`Set myTBs(i).TextBoxEvents = quantity1` (Considering that quantity1 is a textbox) should work?

Comment: `If TypeOf objControl Is MSForms.TextBox Then` Within this loop, you can include/exclude the textboxes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick example that I created for you.

Let's say your userform looks like this

[image]

Now place this in a class module

```
Public WithEvents TextBoxEvents As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub TextBoxEvents_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case Asc("0") To Asc("9")
        Case Else
            KeyAscii = 0
    End Select
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

And place this in the userform

```
Dim myTBs() As New Class1

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Integer, objControl As Control

    For Each objControl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf objControl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
            i = i + 1
            ReDim Preserve myTBs(1 To i)
            Set myTBs(i).TextBoxEvents = objControl
        End If
    Next objControl
    Set objControl = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Now try entering `text/numbers` in any of the textboxes :)

**EDIT**

> @SiddharthRout Wow! Awesome Reply! it's almost like that, but i require that certain textboxes (not all) on the userform could have this restriction. I guess that if i do this Set myTBs(i).TextBoxEvents = quantity1 (Considering that quantity1 is a textbox) should work? – fjatp 6 mins ago

```
        If TypeOf objControl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
            Select Case objControl.Name
            Case "TextBox1", "TextBox3", "TextBox4" '<~~ Include only these
                i = i + 1
                ReDim Preserve myTBs(1 To i)
                Set myTBs(i).TextBoxEvents = objControl
            End Select
        End If
```

Comment: I usually do this with a collection