# Class Object TextBox on Userform available methods

Tags: excel, vba

I have noticed that when I create a Class Module for a Textbox and use that on my forms - by adding via VBA in the form init event - neither the Enter or Exit methods are available. Of course if I just add a textbox to the form they are.

I can get the DblClick method to work fine so my class is setup correctly and my form.init code is also ok.

When I look in the Object browser for MSForms.TextBox I see it doesn't have Enter or Exit methods and presume this is the reason.

There is no urgency for me on this because I noticed it when building my first form that uses my own classes for textbox - Fortunately for what I'm working on now - I don't actually need the Enter or Exit methods, but thought someone might know if there is a work-around because I may need them in the future and for textboxes they are very useful methods

Here is my Class Code named nxTxtV

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents oTxtV As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub oTxtV_Enter()
   ' This method never fires
   MsgBox "Hello World from the Enter Method"
End Sub

Private Sub oTxtV_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   ' This method works fine
   MsgBox "Hello World from the DoubleClick Method for " & oTxtV.Value
End Sub
```

and here's my form initialise code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   Dim xItm As Control, i As Long
   Dim dItm As nxTxtV   ' nxTxtV is the name of my class

   For i = 1 To 5
      Set xItm = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "Column" & i, True)
      With xItm
         .Value = "P" & i
         .AutoSize = False
         .Font.Size = 9
         .Width = 25
         .Height = 250
         .TextAlign = 2 ' Centred
         .SpecialEffect = 0
         .BackColor = RGB(255, 128, 0)
         .WordWrap = True
         .Left = 200 + (i * 27)
         .Top = 5
         .Enabled = True
         .Visible = True
      End With
      Set dItm = New nxTxtV   ' nxTxtV is the name of my class
      Set dItm.oTxtV = xItm
      CodedObjs.Add dItm   ' CodedObjs is declared at module level (form level) as a Collection 
   Next i
End Sub
```

In short, can I get my class to react to Enter & Exit events ?

Addendum - the CodedObjs Declaration

```
Public CodedObjs As New Collection
```

Comment: Sadly, no. You'll have to do a workaround using other events, such as `KeyUp` or `MouseDown`, or a combination.

Comment: @DarXyde Good to Know, at least I can prepare for that at my leisure :-) Thanks

Comment: You could catch the event itself (every event) and look which control fired it. see here for Enter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930517/trigger-enter-field-behaviour-through-class-for-a-control/51936950#51936950

Comment: Background as to why you aren't getting these events: They belong to the more general `Control`  class, from which the other controls "inherit".

Comment: @Cindy Meister Thanks Cindy was hoping someone might clarify that

Comment: @EvR Thanks for that - It looks promising will take me some time to check it out

Comment: @EvR I tried Siddharths answer first but it hogs the processor, then tried your Answer worked too but no processor hogging - Upvoted your answer. Thanks.