# a Sub to Monitor Changes in Texbox in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Index/Match Code to Display a Description of an Item by changing the Label when a Value is Entered in a Texbox , usually the way i do it is put the code on the

```
    Texbox_Change()

        ....Code here

    End Sub
```

but now i have a lot of textboxes and i don't want to write this code one by one
so i tried to put my code on the 'UserForm_Initialize()' but this only runs only once. and i was wandering if there was a way i could create a SUB that Monitors Textbox Changes for all of the Textbox's in my user form.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460211/class-object-textbox-on-userform-available-methods) question.

Comment: Use [Control Arrays](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/)

Comment: Or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24403121/5162073).