# Reducing WithEvent declarations and subs with VBA and ActiveX

Tags: excel, vba, class, activex, worksheet

On a worksheet I have 3 ActiveX objects being TextBox1, TextBox2, ListBox1

Leaving other code out, I have a class clsEvents that contains:

```
Private WithEvents txbControl As MSForms.TextBox
Private WithEvents lisControl As MSForms.ListBox 
Private txbEvents As TextBoxEvents                          
Private lisEvents As ListBoxEvents  

Private Sub txbControl_Change()
     txbEvents.ChangeEvent txbControl
End Sub     

Private Sub lisControl_Change()
     lisEvents.ChangeEvent lisControl
End Sub
```

and the classes TextBoxEvents and ListBoxEvents contain:

```
Public Event Changed(txtBox As MSForms.TextBox)

Public Sub ChangeEvent(txtBox As MSForms.TextBox)
    RaiseEvent Changed(txtBox)
End Sub
```

```
Public Event Changed(ByRef myListBox As MSForms.ListBox)

Public Sub ChangeEvent(lisBox As MSForms.ListBox)
    RaiseEvent Changed(lisBox)
End Sub
```

The worksheet module contains:

```
Public WithEvents tbxEvents As TextBoxEvents
Public WithEvents lisEvents As ListBoxEvents

Private Sub tbxEvents_Changed(tbxBox As MSForms.TextBox)
    Debug.Print "tbxEvents_Changed " & tbxBox.Name
End Sub

Private Sub lisEvents_Changed(lisBox As MSForms.ListBox)
    Debug.Print "lisEvents_Changed " & lisBox.Name
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    Debug.Print "TextBox2_Change"
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Debug.Print "TextBox1_Change"
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    Debug.Print "ListBox1_Changed "
End Sub
```

If I change something in TextBox1 or TextBox2 or ListBox1 the debug window shows that the events first will be send to the worksheet (TextBox1_Change  etc.) followed by tbxEvents_Changed or LisEvents_Changed, so it is working.

What I would like to achieve is replacing the code in clsEvents by something like:

```
Private WithEvents objControl As OLEobject
Private txbEvents As TextBoxEvents                          
Private lisEvents As ListBoxEvents  

Private Sub objControl_Change()
     if (TypeOf objControl.Object Is MSForms.TextBox) Then
     txbEvents.ChangeEvent objControl
     elseif (TypeOf objControl.Object Is MSForms.ListBox) Then
     lisEvents.ChangeEvent objControl
     endif
End Sub
```

How I can achieve a valid definition for WithEvents that will remove the necessity for 'many' event functions in clsEvents?

```
Public WithEvents objControl As ?????
```

Comment: This is not the typical way to use a "control array" in VBA - you have more complexity and still have one event handler per control in your worksheet module.  Did you take this approach for some specific design-related reason?  It's difficult to suggest a "better" approach without knowing the use case for the worksheet.

Comment: In my application I have a worksheet with about 40 tekstboxes, 8 listboxes and 48 labels I want to change color depending on changes in those text- and listboxes.(I can identify the labels because of the names chosen for each control).

On other worksheets I do have a number of objects as well.

So I would like to have ONE event class that raises events for all the textboxes and listboxes.

I want to make it general (checkboxes, optionbuttons,...).
Using C++ that woud be easy by using a base class of TextBox and ListBox and ... as those would have a base class Control.  

.

Comment: @Tim Williams  Of course I will remove TextBox1_Change (etc) on the worksheet, they are only for testing purposes now just to see what events can be handled in clsEvents and the other classes.
I noticed that GotFocus, LostFocus and Click cannot be handled in those classes

Comment: You could have all your clsEvents pass their control object(s) into a single sub which can then respond to the change event based on the control's name

Comment: ...without needing separate event classes or using `RaiseEvent`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Open Notepad and copy code below and paste it in a new txt-file save it als CatchEvents2.cls

```
    VERSION 1.0 CLASS
    BEGIN
      MultiUse = -1  'True
    END
    Attribute VB_Name = "CatchEvents2"
    Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
    Attribute VB_Creatable = False
    Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
    Attribute VB_Exposed = False
    Private Type GUID
          Data1 As Long
          Data2 As Integer
          Data3 As Integer
          Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
    End Type

    #If VBA7 And Win64 Then
          Private Declare PtrSafe Function ConnectToConnectionPoint Lib "shlwapi" Alias "#168" (ByVal punk As stdole.IUnknown, _
                  ByRef riidEvent As GUID, ByVal fConnect As Long, ByVal punkTarget As stdole.IUnknown, ByRef pdwCookie As Long, _
                  Optional ByVal ppcpOut As LongPtr) As Long
    #Else
         Private Declare Function ConnectToConnectionPoint Lib "shlwapi" Alias "#168" (ByVal punk As stdole.IUnknown, ByRef riidEvent As GUID, _
                  ByVal fConnect As Long, ByVal punkTarget As stdole.IUnknown, ByRef pdwCookie As Long, Optional ByVal ppcpOut As Long) As Long
    #End If

    Private EventGuide As GUID
    Private Ck As Long
    Private ctl As Object
    Private CustomProp As String

    Public Sub MyChange()
    Attribute MyChange.VB_UserMemId = 2

    Debug.Print " Change ControlName " & " Type: " & TypeName(ctl) & " CustomProp: " & CustomProp
    End Sub


    Public Sub ConnectAllEvents(ByVal connect As Boolean)
          With EventGuide
              .Data1 = &H20400
              .Data4(0) = &HC0
              .Data4(7) = &H46
          End With
          ConnectToConnectionPoint Me, EventGuide, connect, ctl, Ck, 0&
    End Sub

    Public Property Let Prop(newProp As String)
          CustomProp = newProp
    End Property

    Public Property Let Item(Ctrl As Object)
          Set ctl = Ctrl
          Call ConnectAllEvents(True)
    End Property

    Public Sub Clear()
          If (Ck <> 0) Then Call ConnectAllEvents(False)
          Set ctl = Nothing
    End Sub
```

In your VBA editor you import this File (right click on your VBAproject and choose import)

In a normal module you put in the code below:

```
Private AllControls() As New CatchEvents2

Sub connect()
Dim j As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
ReDim AllControls(.OLEObjects.Count - 1)
    For j = 0 To .OLEObjects.Count - 1
       AllControls(j).Item = .OLEObjects(j + 1).Object
       AllControls(j).Prop = .OLEObjects(j + 1).Name
    Next
End With
End Sub

Sub disconnect()
Dim j As Long
  For j = LBound(AllControls) To UBound(AllControls)
          AllControls(j).Clear
   Next j
      Erase AllControls
End Sub
```

Now when you run the connect sub every change of any activeX control is catched

**Edit: after comment to put in all other events;
Other events: (all these will work on userforms also)**

```
Public Sub MyChange()
Attribute MyChange.VB_UserMemId = 2
Debug.Print "ch"
End Sub

Public Sub MyListClick()
Attribute MyListClick.VB_UserMemId = -610
Debug.Print "cl1"
End Sub

Public Sub MyClick()
Attribute MyClick.VB_UserMemId = -600
Debug.Print "cl2"
End Sub

Public Sub MyDropButtonClick()
Attribute MyDropButtonClick.VB_UserMemId = 2002
End Sub

Public Sub MyDblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Attribute MyDblClick.VB_UserMemId = -601
Debug.Print "dcl"
End Sub

Public Sub MyKeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
Attribute MyKeyDown.VB_UserMemId = -602
Debug.Print "kd"
End Sub

Public Sub MyKeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
Attribute MyKeyUp.VB_UserMemId = -604
Debug.Print "ku"
End Sub

Public Sub MyMouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Attribute MyMouseDown.VB_UserMemId = -605
Debug.Print "md"
End Sub

Public Sub MyMouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Attribute MyMouseMove.VB_UserMemId = -606
Debug.Print "mm"
End Sub

Public Sub MyMouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Attribute MyMouseUp.VB_UserMemId = -607
Debug.Print "mu"
End Sub

Public Sub myKeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
Attribute myKeyPress.VB_UserMemId = -603
Debug.Print "kp"
End Sub
```

Then there are 4 (userform) events: Exit, Enter, AfterUpdate and BeforeUpdate which are events of the container-control which you can't 'catch' with withevents but in this way you can:

```
Public Sub myExit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Attribute myExit.VB_UserMemId = -2147384829
Debug.Print "exit"
End Sub

Public Sub MyAfterUpdate()
Attribute MyAfterUpdate.VB_UserMemId = -2147384832
Debug.Print "au"
End Sub

Public Sub MyBeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Attribute MyBeforeUpdate.VB_UserMemId = -2147384831
Debug.Print "bu"
End Sub

Public Sub MyEnter()
Attribute MyEnter.VB_UserMemId = -2147384830
Debug.Print "enter"
End Sub
```

On a worksheet you've got LostFocus and GotFocus (1541 and 1542) but these I can't get to work, so if anybody knows howto it would be great.
*final remark: It doesnot work on a mac*

Comment: Thanks, it works and can be very useful. But I don't understand WHY sub MyChange is called and I also don't know how I can catch other events. BTW I stumbled upon https://yoursumbuddy.com/userform-event-class-multiple-control-types/ being what I was looking for. But I'm VERY interested in understanding (and probably using) your solution

Comment: The Attribute MyChange.VB_UserMemId = 2 line is doing the work in combination with the ConnectToConnectionPoint API, "=2" is the Change-event . Because of the attributes you have to first save it in a txt file and then import it. I'll edit my post and put in other events in it as well

Comment: IMHO your work is a breakthrough. I looked for catching events in ONE class (or module or sheet) in order to avoid numerous subs for each control but only found partial solutions. It is a pity GotFocus and LostFocus could not be added yet (maybe catching at the worksheet level and rerouting?). I'm sure many people will have a look at this solution and will use it. Thanks for the good work!!

Comment: This is amazing. How did you find those numbers: -2147384831 etc? Is it possible to catch events known from System.Windows.Forms that doesn't exist natively in MSForms, i.e. MouseEnter, MouseLeave?

Comment: Thanks, I used the Microsoft OLE/COM Object viewer

Comment: Thanks for the bounty and nice words Mathieu, I once found the basis of this solution somewhere on a Japanese site, so I don't want to pretend that I am the inventor of all this, even though I have expanded a few things. In this way, as you also describe in your blog, you can capture all events, including those that can be captured via WithEvents. (application and workbook events included). Besides the GotFocus and LostFocus on a worksheet, if you could still figure these out, that would be great.

Comment: For anyone else looking, with Microsoft OLE/COM Object Viewer open, Goto "Type Libraries > Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library (Ver 2.0) > Double click on item" - some might error but one won't. This will reveal the IDL data which will then display DISPIDs `[id(...)]`

Comment: Incase others were curious heres the relevant declerations in the IDL files: [ControlEvents](https://github.com/sancarn/VBA-STD-Lib-Inspiration/blob/master/_IDL/FM20.IDL#L939-L946); [form events](https://github.com/sancarn/VBA-STD-Lib-Inspiration/blob/master/_IDL/FM20.IDL#L964-L1040); [frame events](https://github.com/sancarn/VBA-STD-Lib-Inspiration/blob/master/_IDL/FM20.IDL#L1050-L1126); [label events](https://github.com/sancarn/VBA-STD-Lib-Inspiration/blob/master/_IDL/FM20.IDL#L3057-L3105). I also think Resize() is listed as `void Layout();` DISPID: `id(0x00000302)` or `770` in decimal

Comment: Scratch that - layout is probably layout as in VBA (didn't realise this was an event xD)