# How to use After_Update for TextBox in a class module?

Tags: excel, vba, class, module, textbox

How can I make use of the "After_Update" option in a class module?

After my last question I thought I had it working. I still cannot choose the option "After_Update" in the class module.

I have the following code in my UserForm and Class module:

```vb
Public verzameling As New Collection

Public WithEvents TextBoxEvents As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    For Each ctl In Controls
    
        If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then
            verzameling.Add New invoercontrole
            Set verzameling(verzameling.Count).cl_tekstvak = ctl
        End If
    Next
```

and the next in my class module:

```vb
Public WithEvents cl_tekstvak As MSForms.TextBox  
    
Private Sub cl_tekstvak_BeforeDragOver(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, ByVal DragState As MSForms.fmDragState, ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)
      
    Effect = 2
    If nr = 621 Or nr = 622 Then Effect = fmDropEffectCopy
    Cancel = False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61855925/reducing-withevent-declarations-and-subs-with-vba-and-activex/61893857#61893857

Comment: Do you need the AfterUpdate or BeforeDragOver?

Comment: I need the After_Update

Answer (score 1):

Open Notepad and copy code below and paste it in a new txt-file save it als CatchEvents2.cls

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
    BEGIN
      MultiUse = -1  'True
    End
    Attribute VB_Name = "CatchEvents2"
    Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
    Attribute VB_Creatable = False
    Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
    Attribute VB_Exposed = False
    Private Type GUID
          Data1 As Long
          Data2 As Integer
          Data3 As Integer
          Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
    End Type

    #If VBA7 And Win64 Then
          Private Declare PtrSafe Function ConnectToConnectionPoint Lib "shlwapi" Alias "#168" (ByVal punk As stdole.IUnknown, _
                  ByRef riidEvent As GUID, ByVal fConnect As Long, ByVal punkTarget As stdole.IUnknown, ByRef pdwCookie As Long, _
                  Optional ByVal ppcpOut As LongPtr) As Long
    #Else
         Private Declare Function ConnectToConnectionPoint Lib "shlwapi" Alias "#168" (ByVal punk As stdole.IUnknown, ByRef riidEvent As GUID, _
                  ByVal fConnect As Long, ByVal punkTarget As stdole.IUnknown, ByRef pdwCookie As Long, Optional ByVal ppcpOut As Long) As Long
    #End If

    Private EventGuide As GUID
    Private Ck As Long
    Private ctl As Object
    Private CustomProp As String

    Public Sub MyAfterUpdate()
    Attribute MyChange.VB_UserMemId = -2147384832

        Debug.Print " AfterUpdate ControlName " & " Type: " & TypeName(ctl) & " CustomProp: " & CustomProp
       Select Case TypeName(ctl)
         Case "TextBox": Debug.Print "do something after afterupdate of textboxes"
         Case Else:: Debug.Print "do something else or nothing"
       End Select
    End Sub



    Public Sub ConnectAllEvents(ByVal connect As Boolean)
          With EventGuide
              .Data1 = &H20400
              .Data4(0) = &HC0
              .Data4(7) = &H46
          End With
          ConnectToConnectionPoint Me, EventGuide, connect, ctl, Ck, 0&
    End Sub

    Public Property Let Prop(newProp As String)
          CustomProp = newProp
    End Property

    Public Property Let Item(Ctrl As Object)
          Set ctl = Ctrl
          Call ConnectAllEvents(True)
    End Property
```

In your VBA editor you import this File (right click on your VBAproject and choose import)

In a normal module you put in the code below:

```
Private AllControls() As New CatchEvents2
```

In the code behind your Userform:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim j As Long

ReDim AllControls(Controls.Count - 1)
    For j = 0 To UBound(AllControls)
       AllControls(j).Item = Controls(j)
       AllControls(j).Prop = Controls(j).Name
    Next

End Sub

Sub disconnect()
Dim j As Long
  For j = LBound(AllControls) To UBound(AllControls)
          AllControls(j).Clear
   Next j
      Erase AllControls

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
disconnect
End Sub
```

For more insights and better coding have a look here: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2020/09/30/making-mvvm-work-in-vba-part-2-event-propagation/

Comment: Highly interesting +:)

Comment: This is way out of my league.... I will try to understand this