# How do I force AfterUpdate Event for TextBoxes on a Modal Userform to run after programmaticaly changing their value

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a programmatically designed Excel userform running modaly.
It sometimes crashes and when It does, I will have to start inputting data all over again.
I found a way of saving this volatile data on a worksheet from where I can recover them in case of crash so that I won't need to input them all over again. The problem is that when the TextBoxes are programmaticaly filled, the corresponding AfterUpdate Events do not run.
I have written codes to make them run but I get error that the macro does not exist. I even wrote separate non-Private Subroutines that should do the same thing the AfterUpdate does, but I still get the same error.

Here is the code that recovers data.

```
Private Sub Retrieve_Values()
Dim c, S_Row, E_Row, R_Count As Long, Tname, Vname As String
S_Row = 2
With TempWs
    If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(S_Row, 1)) Then
        If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(S_Row + 1, 1)) Then
            R_Count = .Range(.Cells(S_Row, 1), .Cells(S_Row, 1).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        Else
            R_Count = 1
        End If
        E_Row = S_Row + R_Count - 1
        For c = S_Row to E_Row
            Tname = .Cells(c, 1).Value
            Me.Controls(Tname) = .Cells(c, 2).Value
            Vname = Tname
            Tname = "Help_" & Tname
            Run Tname Vname
        Next
    End If
End With
```

Below is a sample of code it should run

```
Sub Help_BIODATA_DATE_OVERRIDE_TextBox(ByVal Vname As String)
Dim MyValue As String
MyValue = Me.Controls(Vname).Value
If Not MyValue = "" Then
    OV_Date = Extract_Date(MyValue)
    Real_Date = OV_Date
    Client_Dict("DATE OVERRIDE") = OV_Date
Else
    Real_Date = DATE
    Client_Dict("DATE OVERRIDE") = ""
End If
Me.Date_Label.Caption = Date_Display(Real_Date)
Age = Calculate_Age(Real_Date, D_O_B)
Me.Age_Label.Caption = Age
Day_Cash_Collections
Attendace_Register
Account_Summary
```

All codes are in the userform codemodule

Comment: You could use afterupdate (not through withevents) see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61855925/reducing-withevent-declarations-and-subs-with-vba-and-activex/61893857#61893857

Comment: I did not use Class Module for the Events (I have not wrapped my head around it yet). I inserted each event into the Userform Module at runtime

Comment: Best solution would be to fix whatever's causing the crash in the first place (sounds like that would solve lots of issues for you). Failing that, you could 1) Use `_Change` instead of `_AfterUpdate` or 2) Fill the textboxes, then run `_AfterUpdate` sub directly (i.e. spoof the event).

Comment: I thought of using _change event but the problem with that is that the sub will run after every character  I enter into the textboxes. That will slow down the system a lot.

Comment: So the Userform is already there and not "programmatically designed"?  Filling the Userform programmaticaly sounds a bit 'strange' (hence the word User in it) but regarding your question; before putting a value programmaticaly in a textbox and mimic that this is done by a 'User' first set the focus to this Textbox (Me.TextBox1.SetFocus), put in the value and setfocus to next control/textbox. This will trigger AfterUpdate. (However I don't think this is best practice)

Comment: @EvR Thank you. The SetFocus piece did exactly what I wanted. Actually, my user form is programmatically designed at Runtime.