# can't find a way to handle events on Msforms.combobox from oleobject

Tags: vba, combobox, incompatibletypeerror

I hope you're doing well

I created dynamically a combobox, as following

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim oSh As Shape
Set oSh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddOLEObject(Left:=Target.Left, Top:=Target.Top, Width:=Target.Width, Height:=Target.Height, ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1")
With oSh.OLEFormat.Object
    Debug.Print .OLEType
    .Visible = True
    .Name = "test"
    .ListFillRange = "Sheet1!C1:C" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row
    .Activate
End With
```

Next, I want to handle events for each combobox. So after searching on the net, the suitable solution was to create a class named `classe1`, which has the following code :

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents cbEvents As MSForms.ComboBox
Private Sub CbEvents_Enter()
    do something
End Sub
```

And then in the main module, I added

```
Set objMyEventClass.cbEvents = oSh.OLEFormat.Object
```

I get an `incompatible type` error

Can anyone help ? thanks

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the persons who comment, so when I change

```
Set objMyEventClass.cbEvents = oSh.OLEFormat.Object
```

to

```
Set objMyEventClass.cbEvents = oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Object
```

I have no longer errors, but I can't handle any event (I tired to change `_Enter` to `_Change` but it doesn't work)

Comment: Try to change _Enter()  to _Change() enter, exit, before- and afterupdate are not exposed through withevents (although I found a (for now albeit manual) bug to catch these events via withevents ) or have a look here when you need Enter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61855925/reducing-withevent-declarations-and-subs-with-vba-and-activex/61893857#61893857

Comment: The problem is before, it is in the compatibility in the instruction of set

Comment: I do not see al your code, but coming from a shape you'll need another .object => Set objMyEventClass.cbEvents = oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Object

Comment: Now it doesn't show an error, but the events are still not handled even after changing _Enter() to _Change()

Comment: Could you add the complete code for your main and your public variables?

Comment: I use only this code on the worksheet module of "sheet1", and I added the module class `classe1` so this is the complete code

Comment: To reference the ComboBox object itself, try `Set objMyEventClass.cbEvents = oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Object`.