# When I click the button, it doesn't work at all

Tags: vba, ms-word, buttonclick

I have made two ".docm" files that have proper button and "_click()" procedure respectively.
The first "myDocument1" works well, no problem at all.
The other one "myDocument2" does not.
I guess, I need "onAction" or something, but don't know any more.
Pls tell me what to do.

The first one has its codes in "ThisDocument" and
The second one has in "myModule".
The code is single line only "Msgbox OK" both of them.

I'd like to see that it works at the "myModule" not in "ThisDocumet" in case of second file.

[image: Button(s)]

[image: myDocument1's click code]

[image: myDocument2's click code]

[EDIT]
I'd like to add some line of VBA codes that I've used when I made this Button(s). That is not the best routine (wow, a guru says that is even depricated....), but the only route that worked for me after long web searching.

```
Dim myButton
Set myButton = Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1")
    myButton.OLEFormat.Object.TakeFocusOnClick = False
    myButton.OLEFormat.Object.Width = 100
Dim myCompo
Set myCompo = ActiveDocument.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
    myCompo.Name = "myModule"
Dim myModu
Set myModu = myCompo.CodeModule
    myModu.InsertLines 1, _
    "Sub " & myButton.OLEFormat.Object.Name & "_Click()" & vbCr & vbCr & _
    "    Msgbox ""OK""" & vbCr & vbCr & _
    "End Sub"
```

and adding another screen capture, trying to make ClickEvent possible but not attained its goal.
[image: I have failed to find proper Event related section from my VBE.]

Comment: Please do not include links to your google drive in your question.

Comment: so, is there any way to post sample documents ?

Comment: Do you have (maybe by accident) a `CommandButton1_Click()`-routine also in the `ThisDocument`-module of your second workbook?

Comment: @FunThomas  ah, nah. I did not make that event procedure and could not find that anywhere in my VBE. But, when I click it under DesignMode window, the procedure you mentioned created automatically(I do not wanted and not want it though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because this type of Command Button is an ActiveX control, i.e. a COM control, that is contained within the document surface. Word expects event code for the object to be in the `ThisDocument` module and automatically connects that Event code to the COmmandButton1 object when (say) it opens the document.

That's why in the VB Editor, when you have the code open for the `ThisDocument` module, you will see in the dropdown box above the code, on the left hand side, `(General)` and `CommandButton1`. If you select `CommandButton1` in that dropdown, the other dropdown displays the available events. Word uses a naming convention to generate the appropriate Sub for the event using the pattern `objectname_eventname` - in this case, `CommandButton1_Click`.

In any other module, Word doesn't recognise the name `CommandButton1` as having anything to do with the object in the document surface, and doesn't make that connection automatically.

So, if you open myModule and look at the equivalent dropdown, all you will see is `(General)`. Putting a routine called `CommandButton1_Click` in the module just means that you have a regular subroutine. Word does *not* look at the name, recognise its pattern, and connect it to the actual object in the document. So that routine is not called when you click the Button.

In fact you *can* put ActiveX control code in a routine other than ThisDocument, but I certainly don't know what all the consequences of doing that might be. Personally, I think it involves enough additional complication thaat I would leave the code in `ThisDocument` unless I absolutely had to put it somewhere else.

For one thing ActiveX controls are legacy controls (possibly even deprecated). They don't work in any version of Word except Windows Desktop Word. So there is a case for using something else instead.

But if you do want to put event code elsewhere, you can do it this way:

The code has to be in a Class Module (not an ordinary Module). Let's say you create one called `myClass`.

In `myClass`, declare a variable like this:

```
Public WithEvents cb As MSForms.CommandButton
```

(You can't use `WithEvents` in an ordinary module)

Then you should be able to find "cb" in the dropdown above the code window, and you can create its `_Click` event handler, e.g.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Msgbox "OK"
End Sub
```

But then *your code* has to create an object of type `myClass` and connect its `.cb` variable to the actual `CommandButton1` object in your document. So you need to call something, somewhere that does something like this:

```
Dim myC As myClass

Sub CreateMyClass()
Set myC = New myCLass
Set myC.cb = ThisDocument.CommandButton1
End Sub
```

and you probably need something like this in the same module:

```
Sub TearDownMyClass()
Set myC.cb = Nothing
Set myC = Nothing
End Sub
```

You could for example put that code in `ThisDocument` and use a Document Open event or routine to call `CreateMyClass`.

Or if you are trying to take advantage of the facilities available in Class Modules, you could hide the `cb` variable, and write your class module like this:

```
' cb not visible outside the class module.
Private WithEvents cb As MSForms.CommandButton

Public Property Set myButton(myButton As MSForms.CommandButton)
Set cb = myButton
End Property

Public Property Get myButton() As MSForms.CommandButton
Set myButton = cb
End Property

Private Sub cb_Click()
MsgBox "OK"
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
Set Me.myButton = Nothing
End Sub
```

Your other code could be like this:

```
Dim myC As myClass

Sub CreateMyClass()
Set myC = New myCLass
Set myC.myButton = ThisDocument.CommandButton1
End Sub

Sub TearDownMyClass()
Set myC = Nothing
End Sub
```

or, if you only need your class to work specifically with `CommandButton1`, you could use this in the class

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
' You can only do this because CommandButton1 is visible from this module
Set myButton = ThisDocument.CommandButton1
End Sub
```

then in your ordinary module,

```
Sub CreateMyClass()
Set myC = New myCLass
End Sub
```

None of this stops Word from calling any relevant code in `ThisDocument` *as well*. So if you have this new class code and you leave your `CommandButton1_Click` code in `ThisDocument`, Word should pop up two message boxes when you click the Command Button.

If you use either of the other two types of control in your document (legacy Form Fields, which are also available on Mac Word, or Content Controls, which are partly available on Mac Word, be aware the coding needs to be quite different.

Incidentally, if you are trying to write code that encapsulates objects and you like the idea of using private class variables (cf. cb) and property let/set/get statements to access them, you can use those statements in `ThisDocument` because it is a Class Module.

Here are some screenshots from the VB Editor:

[image: Selecting the Class Module in the Project browser]

[image: Related module code]

[image: Select the WIthEvents object variable]

[image: View the related events (partial)]

Comment: wow, that's a great answer. First of All. Thanks A Lot !!!

Comment: after creating WithEvents type variable, I have failed to find proper "event handler" part anywhere in my VBE screen. I have posted at EDIT part of above my main post - the codes that I used to create the button and the screenshot I just made. Thanks again for your precious time and energy.

Comment: what I want to have is quite simple. I'd like to have a Button (any kind, any type and any technology) and its proper events. So, when it needed, I will dump above main post any time and will get a newer (I mean, another) one.

Comment: @LearnAHK I have added some images from the VB Editor - for some reason the titles aren't in there, but they are - select the Class Module, code already written in the class module, select the object you want (cb in the dropdown), view the list of available events.

Comment: Yes, I have done it. All thanks should go to You. It is my first time to make a Class using VBA. Appreciated it, again.

Comment: @LearnAHK - I hadn't seen form your later edit that you were trying to add controls dynamically. AFAIK you can do that and link up event code if the controls are in a UserForm, but I just don't think it works for controls that you create *in the document surface* after the document is opened. i.e. the "modify the VB project programmatically" approch you described is probably the only way. I wouldn't say it's deprecated, but your code has to have access to the VB project, which you can set up on your system but would not typically be the case for an end user system.

Comment: I'll visit this post again and again, to see your detailed and kind replys. That is quite useful for sure. Thanks again.

Comment: @LearnAHK BTW I was looking at something else and came across this Q/A here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61855925/reducing-withevent-declarations-and-subs-with-vba-and-activex/61893857#61893857 . I changed the code of the connect() sub in there to loop through Word InlineShapes instead of Excel ActiveX controls and it seems to work with pre-existing controls on the document. If you provide code to let the user add controls it looks as if you should be able to link new controls into that. Worth a look I think, and some of the comments there may be useful too.

Comment: Hmm, THanks. I'll check it out at my leisure time.