# Handle Exit and Enter event for dynamically created controls with VBA

Tags: vba, events, event-handling

I am working on a VBA project in which I have a some dynamically created ComboBoxes. I want to run events on those controls and for that I created a class which lets me handle the Change and KeyDown events for them. I also need to use the enter and exit events on this controls but I don't know how.
This is the code I have so far:

Class Module:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents DynamicComboBox As MSForms.comboBox

Private Sub DynamicComboBox_Change()

    Debug.Print "Change: " & DynamicComboBox.value
    
End Sub

Private Sub DynamicComboBox_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case vbKeyDown
            Debug.Print "KeyDown " & DynamicComboBox.Name
    End Select
    
End Sub
```

Standard Module:

```
Option Explicit
Dim ControlHandlers As Collection

Sub CreateComboBox(myForm As Object, ctrlAmount As integer)
    Set ControlHandlers = New Collection
    
    'Declare new control
    Dim newComboBox As comboBox
    
    Dim i As Byte
    For i = 1 To ctrlAmount
        
        'Create a new ComboBox
        Set newComboBox = seccion.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
        With newComboBox
            .Name = "cbx" & Mid(.Parent.Name, 3) & i
            .Height = 20
            .Width = 119
            .Left = 129 * i - 39
            .Top = 12
            .Font.Size = 9
        End With
        
        Dim handler As DynamicControlHandler
        Set handler = New DynamicControlHandler
        Set handler.DynamicComboBox = newComboBox
        
        ControlHandlers.Add handler
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look here (especially for enter en exit): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61855925/reducing-withevent-declarations-and-subs-with-vba-and-activex/61893857#61893857