# Excel VBA: AfterUpdate event not triggering for dynamically created userform textbox

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA, I can't get AfterUpdate (or Exit, or anything except Change) to trigger for a dynamically created textbox in a userform. Here's the code that pertains to the textbox in my userform:

```
Public ParticularTextbox As MSForms.TextBox
Dim ParticularTextboxEventClass As New TextboxEventClass

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    .
    .
    .
    Set ParticularTextbox = FrameControl.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txtRating" & RatingsCounter, True)
    .
    .
    .
    Set ParticularTextboxEventClass.TextboxEvents = ParticularTextbox
End Sub
```

And here's my dynamically created textbox code, in its own class module called TextboxEventClass.

This pertains to a music rating tool. The purpose of this is to check the (numeric) value a user enters, and if it's over a maximum number, then bump that value down to the maximum number. (So, for instance, if the max is 10, and the user enters 12, decrease the number to 10.)

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents TextboxEvents As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub TextboxEvents_AfterUpdate()
    MsgBox ("hi")   *'added just to see if I get a reaction out of Excel, but has no other purpose*
    If (Left(TextboxEvents.Name, 9) = "txtRating") Then
        Dim RatingLevel As Integer
        RatingLevel = Right(TextboxEvents.Name, Len(TextboxEvents.Name) - 9)
        If (TextboxEvents.Value > frmGrabSongs.Controls("lblRatingMaximum" & RatingLevel).Caption) Then
            TextboxEvents.Value = frmGrabSongs.Controls("lblRatingMaximum" & RatingLevel).Caption
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If I change this to `Private Sub TextboxEvents_Change()`, it works, but it's annoying since the change event fires every time the user presses a single key. The userform doesn't wait for the user to finish typing. I'd like this event to fire when the user leaves the control,  i.e. when they're done entering their number. But if I change the event to `TextboxEvents_AfterUpdate()` or `TextboxEvents_Exit()`, nothing fires. It's as simple as changing the event to `Change()`, then it works. Only `Change()`.

When I create an `AfterUpdate()` event for a non-dynamically created textbox, it works as I expect: when I tab out of the textbox. But if I put it on my dynamically created textbox instead, nothing happens.

However, when I create an `Exit()` event for a non-dynamically created textbox, I get the error message "Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name," which I don't understand since (1) there's no procedure of the same name on that control, and (2) all the documentation I read about textboxes says that Exit is one of the possible events. :S

Thanks!

Comment: If you select `ParticularTextbox` from the left-hand drop-down at the top of the Class module, you'll see there's no `AfterUpdate` event available in the right-hand drop-down. 
 See here for a solution: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/check-textbox-for-future-date.1127343/

Comment: Or here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61855925/reducing-withevent-declarations-and-subs-with-vba-and-activex/61893857#61893857