# Support for AfterUpdate, BeforeUpdate, Enter and Exit events, Control object in its own class

Tags: vba

I have my own class associated with a control of the MSForms.TextBox type, defined using the WithEvents method. I can handle all TextBox events except AfterUpdate, BeforeUpdate, Enter and Exit. Here's what I do.

1. I have a simple user form with two TextBox controls and one CommandButton button

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private thisTextBox1 As Class1
Private thisTextBox2 As Class1

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Set thisTextBox1 = New Class1
    Set thisTextBox2 = New Class1
    thisTextBox1.Init TextBox1
    thisTextBox2.Init TextBox2
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Set thisTextBox1 = Nothing
    Set thisTextBox2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

2. I have my own Class1 class which should internally handle the events of the TextBox control assigned to it

```
'@Folder("VBAProject")
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents thisTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
Private thisTextBoxControl As MSForms.Control

Public Sub Init(ByVal MyTextBox As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set thisTextBox = MyTextBox
    Set thisTextBoxControl = MyTextBox.Parent.Controls.Item(MyTextBox.Name)
End Sub

Private Sub thisTextBox_Change()
    Debug.Print "thisTextBox_Change " & thisTextBox.Name & " " & thisTextBox.Text
End Sub
```

If the code is written as above, everything works fine, but my class cannot handle the AfterUpdate, BeforeUpdate, Enter and Exit evetnts

3. So if I change the declaration of the internal variable thisTextBoxControl using the WithEvents method, the code will compile correctly. However, when I try to assign an object to thisTextBoxControl I end up with an error *Object or class does not support the set of the events*.

```
Private WithEvents thisTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
Private WithEvents thisTextBoxControl As MSForms.Control

Public Sub Init(ByVal MyTextBox As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set thisTextBox = MyTextBox
    Set thisTextBoxControl = MyTextBox.Parent.Controls.Item(MyTextBox.Name)
End Sub

Private Sub thisTextBox_Change()
    Debug.Print "thisTextBox_Change " & thisTextBox.Name & " " & thisTextBox.Text
End Sub

Private Sub thisTextBoxControl_Enter()
    Debug.Print "thisTextBoxControl_Enter " & thisTextBoxControl.Name
End Sub
```

Does anyone have an idea how to bypass this and how to handle the AfterUpdate, BeforeUpdate, Enter and Exit events inside the class.

Update:
Suggested solution placed in [Reducing WithEvent declarations and subs with VBA and ActiveX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61855925/reducing-withevent-declarations-and-subs-with-vba-and-activex) unfortunately it doesn't work for user form controls.
There is no way I could implement this solution for controls other than ActiveX placed on the sheet. I don't know what the reason is, but it just doesn't work with user form controls.

Comment: Already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61893857/8488913)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reducing WithEvent declarations and subs with VBA and ActiveX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61855925/reducing-withevent-declarations-and-subs-with-vba-and-activex)

Comment: This is (Reducing WithEvent declarations and subs with VBA and ActiveX) indeed a very interesting and informative solution. Unfortunately, this only works with AciveX controls placed in the workshet. Although even here I failed to catch the Enter, Exit, AfterUpdate, BeforeUpdate events. Although I had no problem catch other events.

Unfortunately, in the case of user form controls, I was not able to implement this solution in any way. I don't know what the reason is, but it just doesn't work with user form controls.

Comment: Is this for Excel or another application?

Comment: I tried it in Excel 365 64 bit and in Excel 2016 32 bit.

Comment: @MarekFiołka It also works on Userforms, it works the same way, only the "connection" to the controls is slightly different for Userform see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930517/trigger-enter-field-behaviour-through-class-for-a-control/51936950#51936950